# White Line at bottom of screen when JavaFX application is in full screen

Tags: javafx

I am a beginner for JavaFX

This is what I did to make my JavaFX + spring boot application fullscreen.

```
        stage.setFullScreen(true);
        stage.setMaximized(true);
        stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

There is white line appearing at the bottom

[image]

Does anyone has any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: It seems like the image is simply not big enough. How did you create the scene and set the background?

Comment: Why a DDR flag instead of a German flag?

Comment: @Itai That's not the case. Stage stage = Main.getStage();
  Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
  Rectangle2D bounds = screen.getVisualBounds();

  double screenWidth = bounds.getWidth();
  double screenHeight = bounds.getHeight();

  webView.setPrefHeight(screenHeight);
  webView.setPrefWidth(screenWidth);

Comment: Resolved..Instead of bounds = screen.getVisualBounds() i Have to go bounds = screen.getBounds()